# PHP session variable, check then delete

Tags: php

Code:

```
    if(!$picture) $error = $error."<div>This is a photo site, we require you select a photo.</div>";
    if(!$imgname) $error = $error."<div>You must enter a name for your photo.</div>";
    if(!$description) $error = $error."<div>You must enter a description for your photo.</div>";
    else if(strlen($description) > 500) $error = $error."<div>Your descriptions to long. 500 characters max.</div>";

    if(!$error) {
        $case = 2;

        $max_width_new = 190;

        $make_thumb=1; $make_medium=1; $make_original=1;

        $imagename = "picture";

        $folders = "accounts/".$dbid."/";

        if(!file_exists($folders)) 
            mkdir($folders);

        include("scripts/php/uploadpicture.php");

        if($file) {
        $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","headinth_admin","adobe1234");
        mysql_select_db("headinth_core");
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO pictures (id, uploader, name, description, location, picture, date) VALUES('','$dbid','$imgname','$description','$location','$file_name','$date')");
        $_SESSION['uploaded'] = 1;

        header("location: ?upload");
        }
    } else echo "<div class='green f18 fl coolvetica' style='text-align:left;'>".$error."</div><div class='c20'></div>";
}
if(isset($_SESSION['uploaded'])) {
    echo "<div class='white f18 fl coolvetica' style='text-align:left;'>Your picture was uploaded.</div><div class='c20'></div>";
    unset($_SESSION['uploaded']);
}
?>
```

So it goes through and if everything successful it declares $_SESSION['uploaded'] = 1. Makes sense. Since theres a header it refreshes the page. Then I check if $_SESSION['uploaded'] exists, to see if a photo was just uploaded. If it was then it should send the message "Your photos been uploaded". Then it would have to delete the $_SESSION['uploaded'] variable so it doesn't show up again if the page is refreshed or an invalid submission is made.

The issue is that its just skipping the if(isset($_SESSION['uploaded'])) line and just unsetting the session. So its not echoing the success message. IF i delete the unset it works, just always appears until the entire session is destroyed. So the goal, carry a variable over a page refresh, echo it then remove it.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Can you please try to re-word it to be clearer? What is the exact code you're using, and what is it doing, and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: Just edited it, hope it makes more sense.

Comment: standard question: you did insert a `session_start()` somewhere, did you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`header()` doesn't halt execution of your script. After the `header()` command, the script continues to your `isset()/unset()` block. The solution is to `die` after the `header()`:

```
header("location: ?upload");
die;
```

Comment: I used to always put the die; command but i didn't think it did anything. Now i know thanks! This was giving me so much head ache.

Answer (score 0):

I think its just an issue with the order that you're doing the output and the unsetting.

```
$_SESSION['test'] = 1;
echo "test session variable is: {$_SESSION['test']} <br />";
unset($_SESSION['test']);
echo "test session variable is: {$_SESSION['test']}";
```

will output:

```
test session variable is: 1
test session variable is:
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work for some reason. It insists on deleting before echoing it. Makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: if($_POST['submit']) {
  $_SESSION['uploaded'] = "Uploaded!";
  header("location: ?upload");
 }

 echo $_SESSION['uploaded'];
 unset($_SESSION['uploaded']);
doesnt work either, idk if it has something to do with the header.